# jQuery get text from list item

Tags: jquery

I have a script which works but not the way I want it to.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currUrl = $(location).attr('href');
    var getText = $('#mainNav').find("a[href='" + currUrl + "']").parents("li").last().children("a").text();
    $(".pageTitle").html(getText);
});
```

At the moment my nav structure looks like

```
<div id="mainNav">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us
        <ul>
            <li>Meet the team</li>
            <li>Our History</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Services</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

If you are on the page "About us" the var getText outputs "About us" which is correct.

If I go to "About us > Our History" the var getText still outputs "About us", I'd like it to be "Our History".

How can I get my script to output getText to capture top level and lower level list items.

Sorry no Fiddle as I couldn't show an example using multiple pages.

Thanks

Comment: Is that the actual HTML structure of your navigation? Shouldn't there be `<a>` tags for any of this to work?

Comment: Sorry, I hand typed the navigation and forgot the a tags, the real navigation was huge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`last` will give you the topmost parent. Use `first` for the closest parent.

Comment: Thanks for your help!